# Does it break "terms of use" to store my app settings in SkyDrive?

Tags: windows-8, onedrive

My app runs on Android, iOS, WebSite, WindowsPhone, and now Windows 8. I use SkyDrive already. It's where I store the file(s) my app creates.

It would not be technically difficult to also store my app settings in SkyDrive. This would let me have a "unified" settings experience across devices. That's nice.

Is this allowed? I can do it "technically" can I do it "legally"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It does not**. SkyDrive does not preclude you from using the SkyDrive folders for a repository of a settings file (like a XAML file or something). It is not a violation of ToS.

> This used to NOT be allowed. But, I have confirmed this change with a/the SkyDrive PM.

**Warning**! There is no protected area of SkyDrive for apps to store this sort of information. As a result, the user could delete or tamper with settings files at any time. If you decide to use SkyDrive to store these files, also create a mitigation plan if they are missing or damaged.

Comment: Factually wrong. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826545.aspx, last paragraph. "In general, if your apps store file formats that are understood only by those apps, those file formats don’t belong on SkyDrive." - a Settings file belongs into this category.

Comment: Not to argue with you, but I did get my "facts" from the product team themselves. I am pretty freakin' sure I am 100% accurate on this one. They even give guidance to put it all in ~/AppData/{yourapp}/Settings.xml when you do it. Sorry.